# DOM Xpath object -> $variable

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Here is my html

```
<p class="description-update"> <span>Alternative: </span>나 혼자만 레벨업
<br> <span>View: </span>262343066 views
<br> <span>Author(s): </span>Sung-Lak Jang
<br> <span>Artist(s): </span>a
<br> <span>Genre: </span>  <a href="http://kissmanga.nl/mangas/action">Action </a>, <a href="http://kissmanga.nl/mangas/adventure"> Adventure </a>, <a href="http://kissmanga.nl/mangas/fantasy"> Fantasy </a>, <a href="http://kissmanga.nl/mangas/shounen"> Shounen </a>, <a href="http://kissmanga.nl/mangas/webtoons"> Webtoons</a>,
<br> <span>Type: </span>b
<br> <span>Release: </span>c
<br> <span>Status: </span> Ongoing
<br><span id="bookmark"> <a class="btn-success btn btn_bookmark" href="#" onclick="addBookmark(9492,174881);return false;"> <i style="color: #fff" class="fa fa-flag"></i> <span style="color: #fff">Bookmark</span> 
</a>
</span> <span id="rmbookmark" class="display_bookmark"> <a class="btn-danger btn btn_rmbookmark" href="#" onclick="rmBookmark(9492);return false;"> <i style="color: #fff" class="fa fa-times"></i> <span style="color: #fff">Remove Bookmark</span> 
</a>
</span>
```

and here is my php

```
$alternative = 'nextSibling->nodeValue';
$info = $xpath->query('.//*[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," description-update ")]/span');
echo $info->item(1)->nextSibling->nodeValue;
echo $info->item(1)->$alternative;
```

The first echo output is **262343066 views** which is what i wanted. But in the second echo i got this error

```
Undefined property: DOMElement::$nextSibling->nodeValue
```

How do i fix the second echo so the output is **262343066 views**?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its working now

```
$alternative = explode('->','nextSibling->nodeValue');
$info = $xpath->query('.//*[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," description-update ")]/span');
echo $info->item(1)->nextSibling->nodeValue; //262343066 views (WORK)
echo $info->item(1)->{$alternative[0]}->{$alternative[1]}; //262343066 views (WORK)
```